# The best way for localize an app with Xcode 9 and Swift 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, localization

I used to localize my app using `Localizable.string` files and providing a key for every text on my project.

Currently I'm working on a project using Xcode 9 and Swift 4 and for the first time I'm using Storyboards (yes, it sounds weird but I always used SpriteKit without using Storyboards) and I'm a little bit confused how to handle the localization with that. Basically my question is:

Should I use Storyboard localizations for `UILabel` or should I implement everything in `Localizable.string` and give the label a value through code?

Any tips in order to understand which is the best way to localize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use `Localizable.string` instead of Storyboard localizations, because ids of the labels in storyboard might change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will definitely use `Localizable.strings` file then

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a better/worse solution. It depends on the purpose of your `UILabel`. If it's an element that doesn't change during lifecycle of the app, you may prefer using directly Storyboard localization. Instead, if the label could have different values, I recommend you to set programmatically your localized strings.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most reliable solutions I found, This exactly works for me .

1st we need to use a storyboard and create localization string file. which will automatically create ID to all the objects. 
Follow this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/)

Then we can use one library [MCLocaliztion](https://github.com/Baglan/MCLocalization) which will pick respective translation string based on ID. What we have to do, we need to prepare a proper json based on Objects ID.

Hope it helps.